# Junit testing a method that returns a callback

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a callback routine that is used to handle Google pubsub messages:

```
private MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
    return (message, consumer) -> {
        if (message.getAttributesMap() != null) {
            method1();
        } else {
            method2();
        }
    };
}
```

I need to write a junit 4 test to verify which method (1 or 2) is invoked, given a message.  I know how to do that for a straighforward method, but not a method that returns a callback. can anyone provide a quick example of how to do that?

Comment: Well I'd expect you to call the callback within your tests - in one test you'd call it with a message with attributes, and in the other you'd call it with a message without attributes.

Answer (score 3):

So you've got either a structure or conceptual challenge.  I'll put it this way, what's your **unit under test**?

If it's just the callback, i.e. "when callback is called with such and such message, it should call method1", then `method1` needs to become part of your test harness.  In other words you need to spy on `method1` and `method2` so you can capture and assert on when they are and are not called.  The challenge here is that the more "clever" you get with spies and mocks, the more complicated and brittle your tests are.  You may need to separate `getMessageReceiver` from the class containing `method1` and `method2` in this case.

If it's the class containing the `getMessageReceiver`, `method1` and `method2` methods, then you need to invoke the callback and assert on the externalities of `method1` and `method2`.  E.g. if calling `method1` invokes `someDelegate.doAThing()`, inject a mock of `someDelegate` and assert that `doAThing` is called.